# Start up commands

Tags: 18.04

I want to run a command or script as root while booting, like just before login. I have tried the solution i used until 17.10, but after a fresh install of 18.04, I no longer have an /etc/rc.local. The command is hdparm -y /dev/sdc to put that drive into sleep, but it only works with root.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/q/1047776/21005

Answer (score 1):

You can just create the file `/etc/rc.local` and make it executable, then put this in it:

```
#!/bin/sh
hdparm -y /dev/sdc
```

Comment: Ok, I'll try it later.

Comment: @Dragon8oy so did it work? You could examine the status of systemd rc.local.service by `systemctl status rc-local.service`.

Comment: I think it worked, I don't have that install anymore and removed the drive I was powering down since then.