# Is /etc/rc.local still the preferred way to run scripts at startup on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: server, bash, scripts, 18.04

I used to run several scripts at startup to set things the way I want my server running. After migrating to Ubuntu 18.04, I am having trouble with a few scripts and I am just wondering if this is still the preferred method to run shell scripts automatically after rebooting?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/719157/158442

Comment: It depends. Best to properly configure your server so that you don't need any scripts. Second choice is to write a proper systemd script. We really can't advise you unless you post your scripts

Comment: I would make an entry in a  runlevel. It is the recommended way.

Comment: @abu_bua "n recent versions of Linux systems such as RHEL 7, Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the concept of runlevels has been replaced with systemd targets." (https://www.ostechnix.com/check-runlevel-linux/)

Comment: @dsstorefile1 so what is the recommended way?

Answer (score 2):

Following Ubuntu 16.04 traditional init startup scripts have been superseded by the systemd service and its configurations. Most of the scripts or script instructions were rewritten into so called systemd unit files. Therefore I would recommend to setup a systemd service for your custom startup scripts.

Create `/etc/systemd/system/foo.service` with content:

> [Unit]
>   Description=Setup foo
>   After=network.target
>
> [Service]
>   Type=oneshot
>   ExecStart=/opt/foo/setup-foo.sh
>   RemainAfterExit=true
>   ExecStop=/opt/foo/teardown-foo.sh
>   StandardOutput=journal
>
> [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

Replace with your parameters accordingly.  This service definition will run `/opt/foo/setup-foo.sh` on each startup.

Remember to load and enable the service:

> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
>   sudo systemctl enable foo.service

For more info take a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/d006f12914b21198ee43).